# Why the processing time behaves different with these two functions using parallel?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Imagine I have two functions, one is a simple mean of sum of squares, and the other, a little more elaborated that computes a regression, that I want to apply to  the lines of a "big" matrix or data frame.

In order to take advantage of multiple cores (on Windows) I tried the `parallel` package and got very different results for the two functions using the same sequence of commands.

For the apparently more complex function (regression) it appears that the time reduction is significant using more cores (Here I show a result from a PC with 3 cores and a PC with 12 cores, the behavior is similar with up to 11 cores, the time reduction decreases with more cores).
[image]
[image]

But for the "simple" function, mean of squares, the time of executions is very variable, almost erratic (also tested with up to 11 cores). 
[image]
[image]

First, Is there a reason why this is happening? Second, I imagine there are other ways to do that task, can you suggest any?

Here is the code to generate the plots:

```
library(parallel)
nc=detectCores()-1  #number of cores
myFun =function(z) coef(lm(rep(1,length(z))~z)) #regression
myFun2 =function(z) sum(z^2)/length(z) # mean  of squares
my.mat = matrix(rnorm(1000000,.01,0.4),ncol=100) #data
# using FUN = myFun 
# Replicate 10 times
for(j in 1:10){
ncor=2:nc
timed=c()
for (i in seq_along(ncor)){
cl <- makeCluster(mc <- getOption("cl.cores", ncor[i]))
stime <- Sys.time()
res=parApply(cl = cl, X = my.mat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = myFun)
tm=Sys.time()-stime
timed[i]=tm
stopCluster(cl)
}
# no cores
stime <- Sys.time()
res=apply(my.mat, MARGIN = 1, FUN = myFun)
tm=Sys.time()-stime
(dr=data.frame(nc=c(1,ncor),ts=as.numeric(c(tm,timed))))
plot(dr,type="l",col=3,main=j)
#stopCluster(cl)
if (j==1)fres1=dr else fres1=merge(fres1,dr,by="nc")
}
plot(fres1[,1:2],type="l",col=2,ylim=range(fres1[,-1]))
for(i in 3:11)lines(fres1[,i],col=i+1)

# For the second plot use the same code but change FUN = myFun2
```

Comment: I guess that's because using multiple cores causes overhead. If the work to perform is too small, it just does not pay off, i.e. the added overhead per core is equal or even greater than what you can save.